# From textbox input to sending hexadecimal through serial in C#

Tags: c#, hex, type-conversion

I have a textbox in my C# GUI in which I want the user to let it enter hexadecimal values. Example:

input = `0x01 0xD 0x0A`

After that, I want the hexadecimal value to be converted to bytes. What would my approach to this?

I do know in the end I need to use:

```
bytes = new byte[amount of hex values]
                {
                   //here are my hexadecimal values 

                };
```

But what dynamic approach could I use to convert the string to separate hexa-values at runtime?

I have found:

```
string str = "7E 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF";
byte[] bytes = str.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
serialport.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

but this wouldn't work at runtime (the amount of hexa values is set at compile time?)

Comment: Are you sure you want the user to enter that redundant 0x prefix for each value? The prefix only makes sense in a programming language to tell the compiler the value is hex.

Comment: hmm not really but it was just an example.

Comment: LINQ: var bytes = yourInput.Text.Split( ' ' ).Select( h => byte.Parse( h, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier ) ).ToArray();

Comment: great!!!!! can you submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ:

```
var bytes = yourInput.Text.Split( ' ' ).Select( h => byte.Parse( h, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier ) ).ToArray();
```